# Troubleshooting opaque Cloud Run 502

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My Cloud Run app responds with 200 on most requests, but certain HEAD requests throw 502. When I run the Docker container locally it consistently returns 200.

Even my in-app access logs say that the web server has returned 200, yet I get 502 from `Google Frontend`. No other messages are logged between the in-app access log's successful response and the failure from Cloud Run.

[Logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DohNf.png)

How do I debug this opaque error? I've tried everything in the [Cloud Run troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried checking this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup) to help you add more details to your question?

Comment: Thanks Alex, unfortunately it looks like Cloud Debug for Go isn't available on Cloud Run https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/go